# Unobtrusive AJAX error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined"

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-ajax

Example code:
In an MVC 5 project in Visual Studio, I have set up the following controller and views:

**Controller**

*TestController.cs*

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public PartialViewResult MyPartialView1()
    {
        return PartialView("PartialView1");
    }

    public PartialViewResult MyPartialView2()
    {
        return PartialView("PartialView2");
    }
}
```

**Views**

*Index.cshtml*

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing Unobtrusive AJAX</h1>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Partial 1", "MyPartialView1", "Test",
                new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "contentShouldLoadHere", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
    |
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Partial 2", "MyPartialView2", "Test",
                new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "contentShouldLoadHere", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
    <div id="contentShouldLoadHere">
         <p>This will get replaced.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*PartialView1.cshtml*

```
<h1>Test 1</h1>
```

*PartialView2.cshtml*

```
<h1>Test 2</h1>
```

**Question**

If I have understood correctly, clicking "Partial 1" should load the contents of "PartialView1" into the HTML element with an ID of "contentShouldLoadHere".  Instead, clicking "Partial 1" causes a normal page load of the MyPartialView1 action (`~/Test/MyPartialView1)`, and in the Chrome dev tools console I get the following JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is undefined
```

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can fix it?

**Notes**
- I have confirmed via Chrome Dev Tools that both scripts are being correctly loaded.
- The HTML for the link generated by the @Ajax helper is:

```
<a href="/Test/MyPartialView1" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, updateTargetId: &#39;contentShouldLoadHere&#39; });">Partial 1</a>
```

Comment: You html should look like `<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#contentShouldLoadHere" href="/Test/Partial1">Partial 1</a>` so something weird here

Comment: Do you have any other scripts loaded. I think this markup was used with `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js`

Comment: @StephenMuecke nope. In my real page I do, but the sample page I'm experimenting with has only those scripts included, the output is exactly as shown in the View file with the exception of helper generated HTML.

Comment: Have you disabled unobtrusive javascript i.e. set `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=false`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you!  You gave me a clue on where to look. My web.config did not have `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>` in it.  I added that and it fixed it. Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Also found a bit more about it [in this blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html) if your interested.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The blog link is excellent, cheers mate.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The html your generating for the link is generated if unobtrusive javascript has been disabled. You can enable it in the view with

```
@{HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;}
```

or for the application (in `web.config`) with

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Your rendered html should then look like

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#contentShouldLoadHere" href="/Test/Partial1">Partial 1</a>
```

and will work with the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file

Comment: You can put `HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;` in Global.asax.cs, too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, just adding the 'HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;' did not fix it. I had to also add the 'HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;'. Adding code in Global.asax for both settings fixed it.