# ASP.Net MVC Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive.

I have a link like this:

```
   @Ajax.ActionLink("...
```

I got this javascript error when i click on the link:

```
  Can't find variable Sys
```

the onclick event on the a href generated by asp is:

```
  Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event)
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the error messge ?

Comment: Sorry mistake i've edit the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008435/unobtrusive-ajax-error-uncaught-referenceerror-sys-is-not-defined